# How to split up and divide long string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string of data that I would like to split up, for example my one string contains multiple characters, their stats and abilities they each have.

**Full String:**

```
"Andy,135,Punch-Kick-Bite-Headbutt|Tom,120,Bite-Slap-Dodge-Heal|Nathan,105,Bite-Scratch-Tackle-Kick"
```

So the above string has the characters seperated by "|" and the abilities that are seperated by "-".
I managed to divide them up by each character so its "Andy,135,Punch-Kick-Bite-Headbutt" in one index of array by doing this:

```
string myString = "Andy,135,Punch-Kick-Bite-Headbutt|Tom,120,Bite-Slap-Dodge-Heal|Nathan,105,Bite-Scratch-Tackle-Kick";

string[] character = myString.ToString().Split('|');
for (int i = 0; i < character.Length; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("Character data:    " + character[i].ToString());
}
```

Now How would I turn something like "**Andy,135,Punch-Kick-Bite-Headbutt**" and only retrieve the stats into a stat array so its "Andy,135" and pull Abilities into a string array so it is: "Punch-Kick-Bite-Headbutt"

So I would have my statArray as "Andy,135" and abilityArray as "Punch-Kick-Bite-Headbutt"

Comment: My suggestion: store your data as JSON and use a serializer to read it. That way you have an easy-to-understand format and you don't have to spend your time writing a serializer.

Comment: Use `string.Split` again, but this time split on `,`? You can then glue the name and stat together again. Alternatively, use `LastIndexOf`, or `IndexOf`, to get the position of the `,`, then use `string.Substring` to grab the two parts of the string on either side of it

Comment: Do you need the string to have that format in the first place? What about e.g. JSON?

Comment: @derHugo Its for an asset that I am using as tool, so it requires single string data. I am also looking into JSON next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I would strongly recommend defining class to store that data:

```
public class Character
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Stat { get; set; }
    public string[] Abilities { get; set; }
}
```

The I would write following LINQ:

```
// First split by pipe character to get each character (person)
// in raw format separately
var characters = longString.Split('|')
    // Another step is to separate each property of a character,
    // so it can be used in next Select method.
    // Here we split by comma
    .Select(rawCharacter => rawCharacter.Split(','))
    // Finally we use splitted raw data and upon this, we create
    // concrete object with little help of casting to int and
    // assign abilities by splitting abilities list by hyphen -
    .Select(rawCharacter => new Character() 
      {
          Name = rawCharacter[0],
          Stat = int.Parse(rawCharacter[1]),
          Abilities = rawCharacter[2].Split('-'),
      })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation would go a long way, I think. Code-only answers are discouraged. Also, calling two different things (with different data types) `rawCharacter` is a bit confusing IMO. You could use a single `Select`, instead of chaining them

Comment: @canton7 thanks for remarks, but after adding comments, I think it is more clear to chain `Select`s :)

Comment: Thank you for this, it did what I wanted.